# What compiler/interpreter does chrome use for HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

For JavaScript, I know Chrome uses the v8 engine, but v8 only interprets and runs JavaScript.

What about CSS and HTML? What does Google Chrome use to compile and interpret them?

Comment: Have a look at [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine)).

Answer (score 0):

They are all part of [Blink](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine)) which powers Chromium.

Core implementation is available here:

- HTML: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/core/html
- CSS: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/core/css/